# Is there a way I can write a tmux plugin to select a single line?

Tags: tmux

The acme "editor" has this awesome feature where you can click on some output like

```
foobar.foo:212
```

and acme opens that file at that line number.

I'd love to add support for something like that into tmux (I don't think anything like it exists already)

The way I see it working is that you enter copy-mode, place your cursor over a line and then run a command which opens that file on that line in an editor of your choice. My question is - I don't see anyway I could implement a feature like that without forking tmux. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use acme but I use Emacs. In Emacs one can pass a filename to open `+<LINE_NUM> <FILENAME>`, for example: `+13 ~/HINTS`. I added the following to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind C-e run "tmux save-buffer - | xargs emacs"
```

Now I can just write `+1 ~/HINTS` in terminal, enter copy mode and copy this string and press `C-b C-e` to open line 1 in file `~/HINTS` with Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `send-keys` directly in `copy-mode`, but you can do something like this:

```
bind-key O send-keys space e enter \; new-window open-at-line \: paste-buffer \; send-keys enter
```

Then, in copy-mode, put the cursor on the first letter of `filename:line` and hit `<prefix> O`.

This will copy the filename and line number (`send-keys space e enter`), open a new window with the `open-at-line` command, which is a shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
read combo
eval `vim ${combo:s/:/ -c :/}`
```

That gets the combined `filename:line` from `paste-buffer` and passes that to `vim`.